# Make 'ctags' detect fortran's "module procedure" pattern?

Tags: ctags, xref, etags, fortran

I am using `ctags` to index fortran files for code navigation in Emacs with <kbd>M-.</kbd>.

In doing so I have noticed that it doesn't recognize declarations of the form

```
MODULE PROCEDURE MySubroutineName   ! or
MODULE SUBROUTINE MySubRoutineName
```

which arise when using the `SUBMODULE` feature.

In "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497538/ctags-and-fortrans-interfaces" a similar issue occurred, but there the solution was merely to enable a feature, that isn't enabled by default. For submodules no such feature exists.

Is it possible to make ctags aware of this construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctags supports regular expression which could be used to parse tags.

Add below code into `~/.ctags`,

```
--regex-fortran=/^[ \t]*MODULE[ \t]+(PROCEDURE|SUBROUTINE)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\2/s,subroutines/
```

`hello.f` is like,

```
MODULE PROCEDURE MySubroutineName1   ! or
MODULE SUBROUTINE MySubRoutineName2
```

Then run `ctags -e hello.f` to test.

See https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ctags+regular+expression&t=ffab&atb=v202-1&ia=web on regular expression syntax.

Please note exuberant-ctags will load `~/.ctags` by default but universal-ctags loads `~/.ctags.d/*.ctags` instead of `~/.ctags`. So you might need run `ln -s ~/.ctags ~/.ctags.d/1.ctags` if you replace exuberant-ctags with universal-ctags.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred, because `ctags` on my system was the "Exuberant Ctags" implementation, whose latest version is from 2009; The language feature I needed support for was standardized only in 2008.

I solved the issue by asking the administrator to install "Universal Ctags", which should be the best-maintained variant of `ctags`.

---

I'll leave this question open in the hope that someone knows a way to add support, when using a newer ctags implementation isn't possible (e.g. tight software guidelines in a company, or when encountering a feature not yet supported out of the box by any implementation).

Comment: Through fixing is not promised,  it is worth to make an issue at u-ctags's GitHub repo page.